# Magento Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated

Tags: magento2

Deprecated: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\DemoWebsite\vendor\magento\framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader.php on line 34

Comment: This issue should be related to PHP version. Try downgrading the php version and check again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was solved when i changed my xampp php version to 7.4 isntead of 8. Because Magento 2 doesn't support php v8 Yes Now Working